Uniform distribution problem solving
On a street segment p of length $13 m$, a car of length $5 m$ parks completely at random. What is the probability that another car of the same length can fit?
I am not sure whether I am correct but this feels like a uniform distribution problem, but otherwise I am completely lost to how to solve it. I think if we have $13m$ to park but one car of length $5m$ is already parked there then we only have $8 m$ left. But the probability that we can fit in another $5m$ long car depends on how the first car is parked. If it is parked between 4 to 9 meters then we can't fit in another 5m car but if it is parked anywhere else we will. I am not sure whether I am right this far but can't get further than that.
Thanks beforehand!

Consider one end (left end which I'll consider to be the back end) of the car to be at $x$ meters away from $0$.
if say $3<x<5$, then the remaining space is $x$ meters behind the car(which is less than $5$) and $13-(x+5)=8-x$ meters infront of the car (which is less than $5$ as $x>3$)
(Draw a picture of the above to make things clear)
This makes it impossible for the second car to fit.
Now suppose $x<3$, then there is a space of $8-x$ meters in front of the car, and this is greater than $5$.
And if $x>5$, then again, we can park the 2nd car behind the first car as we have a space of $x$ meters.So the problematic zone is $3<x<5$.
Now where can the left end of the car lie? Well, the car has to fit within the $13$ meter mark. So the left end can be atmost at the $8$ meter mark.
So now, the question becomes that of an uniform distribution. You have that the left end of the car is uniformly distributed in $[0,8]$ and the problematic zone is the interval $[3,5]$.
So the probability that another car cannot be parked is $\dfrac{5-3}{8}=1/4$ and hence, the probability that another car can fit is $3/4$
